# C program can't find directories from directory /etc/

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a code that checks if a directory exist. When I try to check if /etc/init.d exist, it just can't find it. I tried to look for another directory(/usr/lib/) and it worked.
Here is my code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int directory_exists(){
   DIR* dir = opendir("/etc/init.d");
   if (dir) {
      /* Directory exists. */
      printf("yes\n");
      closedir(dir);
   } else if (ENOENT == errno) {
      printf("no\n");
   } else {
      /* opendir() failed for some other reason. */
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The check should work - are you on a system that doesn't have an `/etc/init.d` directory?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does your program run into the `ENOENT` branch or in the final `else`?

Comment: Works fine on Fedora 36.

Comment: I'm using an PopOS, I checked and it has the directory I'm trying to find.

Comment: `ENOENT` could be set due to `errno` carrying that value from some random previous call that failed. Maybe actually check if the opendir failed first, or also zero `errno`?

Comment: @thrig The program only checks `ENOENT` if `opendir` returned `NULL` which actually is the indication for an error that you suggest.

Comment: Just for curiosity.... Does it work if you execute using `sudo`?

Comment: Use `perror()` when an error occurs, so you see the reason.

Comment: It worked using `sudo`. Thanks guys.